# Delay / Freezing OF WPF ui

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I have been working on a WPF application, and my application freezes as I Navigate from one window to another, The first window is for Login and the second window is the main window where work is carried out (the application is a form based application where Data is Written to and from a Database like MySQL)

#### 2nd Window Operations

In the second window, I have created a Menu by placing **Icons** in a **List** and then Handling their **click events** to navigate to a page

These Pages are not the UI Element 'Page' but are Usercontrols I refer to them by Pages for Simplicity, and these usercontrols are added to the grid by `grid.children.Add(UsercontrolName);`.       . . . . . This part of adding usercontrols as you can see is done in code behind(C#) and not by XAML

#### Click Event Handling

All i do is I simply shift the visibilty of a Usercontrol, so for example an icon that is related to a say Usercontrol A, that usercontrols visibity is set to visible and all other usercontrols visibilty is set to Collapsed, by default all usercontrols Visibilty is set to Collapsed

## The Problem

What I do not Understand is what is causing this Lag or Freeze or even how to find or figure this out, I understand that WPF is an STA and UI elements such as a Grid/usercontrols should be run on the main thread , so if we Used Dispatcher to resume to the Main thread the UI wont freeze but it would Still take time to load, and I want to stop this delay

Although Contradictory I still think its the **Adding of Usercontrols to the Grid** is causing slow speeds, bcz these Usercontrols have numerous UI elements that I am using from a library called MaterialDesigninXAML, its a form based application so have like 8 Usercontrols all of them with textboxes and Imageboxes and buttons etc, and adding these Usercontrols at once is causing the Overhead

**And I am stuck at this Delay / Freeze of the UI**

The code below is a ditto example of my original code, I posted the example bcz my code is lengthier with the same problem

### this is the part of the code that lags

```
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        
            {
                UserControl usc;

                usc = new Y1();
                usc.Tag = "Memeber";
                no.Children.Add(usc);
                 
                Y4 usc2 = new Y4();
                usc2.Tag = "CheckBoxList";
                no.Children.Add(usc2);

                Y5 usc3 = new Y5();
                usc3.Tag = "Reports";
                no.Children.Add(usc3);

                ShowUserContro("Memeber");
            }
        );
```

---

```
    private void ShowUserContro(string v)
    {
        foreach (UIElement item in no.Children)
        {
            if (item is UserControl)
            {
                UserControl x = (UserControl)item;
                if (x.Tag != null)
                {
                    if (x.Tag.ToString().ToUpper() == v.ToUpper())
                    {
                        x.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowUserContro((((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name));
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you have an issue with your code, but it seems that no code exists in your post.

Comment: If you are using click handlers on your menu then you have a **memory leak** in that list. If you use **names** in your templates, you have a memory leak. Forms do **NOT** exist in WPF. When you "hide" a user control it has to be created first in order to be hidden (expensive). You should look into how WPF works as it is **NOT** winforms. To overcome this use DataTemplates with ViewModels. Page means you are using a Frame which doesn't inherit data context, which is how WPF works. Also there is a chance that you navigate to a "page" using strings. How do you test this app?

Comment: In order to determine what is the cause of your lag, I suggest you turn on Visual Studio diagnostic tools.  They will give you a nice timeline of where you application is spending all of its time.  This should allow you to set debug breakpoints appropriately and pinpoint which slow operations need to be made asycnchronous

Comment: @user9938 I have Included the code

Comment: @XAMlMAX I am not using a page I just refereed to it that way in verbal flow. Yes, I did create the User control as I have just recently update the question. I don't use MVVM cuz I have no experience in MVVM, my aim is to simply enable navigation except the freeze, learning MVVM just to enable navigation for a Project on the brink of completion felt useless, I plan on learning it and updating the project with that architecture